# RegEx to delete all XML data outside of specified tags

Tags: regex, xml, notepad++, find-replace

I am using the latest and greatest version of NotePad++. Is it possible for a RegEx to delete all text and tags I don't need and only leave behind text and tags I need? The tags I need to remain look like this:

```
<warning>I need this text to remain intact together with accompanying tags.</warning>
```

There must be around 500 of these WARNING tag pairs nested within a variety of XML levels. I would like the RegEx to delete all data that exists outside of these WARNING tags but not the opening and closing warning tags themselves or the text within the tags. Below are four different RegEx variations I tested out and they all eliminate the text located within the warning tags after performing a Find&Replace operation therefore they are no help:

```
<warning>[^<>]+</warning>

<warning>[^>]+</warning>

<warning>(.+?)</warning>

<warning>.*?</warning>
```

I would tremendously appreciate any help that will assist me in developing a RegEx that will perform the data clean up task I need to perform.

Comment: Can you give an example text snippet? This isn't something you should really be doing with regexes.

Answer (score 0):

I use notepad++ regex find and replace below seems works for me. Remember to select regular expression.
Search and replace both regex below with empty. Require 2 steps though, not perfect yet

1st replace remove all lines that not startswith **warning**

2nd replace remove all the empty lines leaving only lines with **warning**

```
^(?!\s*?<warning>).*?$
^\s*
```

Comment: Skycc, thanks for your post. I tested it out and it deletes all of the data. It does not leave behind the WARNING tags or text within the WARNING tags.

Comment: Glad it solve your issue, you could accept the answer or vote the snswer useful, there is a checkbox left to answer 